# Common Lisp Exercise

Tags: common-lisp

Im have been doing research about common lisp , I already read examples and some pdf's , my professor assigned several problems as homework I can only use cons, append, list, equal, defun, car, cdr, cond , one of the was to the delete an specific number of a list for example `(remove 2 '(1 2 3 4)` , result: `(1 3 4)` , my code:

```
                                 (define (delete ele listx )
                                    (cond ( null? listx)
                                         '( ))
                                       ( ( equal? ele (car listx))
                                       (delete ele (cdr listx)))
                                  (else 
                                    (cons (car listx)
                                       (delete ele (cdr listx))))))
```

That was not to difficult but now I have to create a function that delete a element between two like this -> `(delete'(a b c d e f) 2 5)`   ;delete between third and fourth (a b e f)

I havent tried anything yet , just research and I started some code but not sure

```
( defun deletemiddle (index1 index2 listx)
   (cond (( null listx) 0 )
        (( = valor1 (1) )
          ((cons (car listx)
```

Comment: I would expect `(delete'(a b c d e f) 2 5)` should result in `(a b f)` at least, and possibly even `(a b)`. I can't figure out a logic by which it would result in `(a b e f)`.

Answer (score 1):

- If starting index is 0 or less and ending index is over 0, drop the element and recurse
- Otherwise cons the element and recurse

When you recurse, cdr of list, and both indices decremented by 1.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific, I can only use cons, append, list, equal, defun, car, cdr, cond

Comment: Then the only change needs to be not using `&optional` - make it a mandatory boolean parameter. If you want to change the function signature to not require it, use an auxiliary function that just calls the main function with deletion mode off. Everything else is the same as in your code, just with slightly different logic.

Comment: If you are not allowed to use T and NIL, empty list is false, and anything else (`1`, `cdr`...) is true... Though I guess it looks weird if you use `cdr` for true :D

Comment: I can also use T and NIL that's not a problem

Comment: Based on your answer , I tried on paper , but not sure if that would work , for the logic is different based on my question , if I pass two arguments , the argument that is on the middle of those should be erased  like this: (delete   2  5 '(a b c d e f) ) ;delete between third and fourth the       result : (a b e f)

Comment: Ah, I failed to notice you're specifying _indices_, not element like before. I'll change the algorithm. You don't even need the explicit deletion mode.

Answer (score 0):

Here a different traces that could help finding out how to recursively build the resulting list:

```
  0: (DEL (1 2 3 4 5 6) 2 5)
    1: (DEL (2 3 4 5 6) 1 4)
      2: (DEL (3 4 5 6) 0 3)
        3: (DEL (4 5 6) 0 2)
          4: (DEL (5 6) 0 1)
          4: DEL returned (5 6)
        3: DEL returned (5 6)
      2: DEL returned (5 6)
    1: DEL returned (2 5 6)
  0: DEL returned (1 2 5 6)

  0: (DEL (1 2 3 4 5 6) 2 8)
    1: (DEL (2 3 4 5 6) 1 7)
      2: (DEL (3 4 5 6) 0 6)
        3: (DEL (4 5 6) 0 5)
          4: (DEL (5 6) 0 4)
            5: (DEL (6) 0 3)
              6: (DEL NIL 0 2)
              6: DEL returned NIL
            5: DEL returned NIL
          4: DEL returned NIL
        3: DEL returned NIL
      2: DEL returned NIL
    1: DEL returned (2)
  0: DEL returned (1 2)

  0: (DEL (1 2 3 4 5 6) 0 3)
    1: (DEL (2 3 4 5 6) 0 2)
      2: (DEL (3 4 5 6) 0 1)
      2: DEL returned (3 4 5 6)
    1: DEL returned (3 4 5 6)
  0: DEL returned (3 4 5 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(defun deletemiddle (list idx1 idx2 &optional (curr 0))
  (cond ((null list) '())
        ((< idx1 curr idx2) 
         (deletemiddle (cdr list) idx1 idx2 (1+ curr)))
        (t (cons (car list) 
                 (deletemiddle (cdr list) idx1 idx2 (1+ curr))))))

;; (< idx1 curr idx2) is short for: (and (> curr idx1) (< curr idx2))
```

```
(deletemiddle '(a b c d e f) 2 5)
;; => (A B C F)
```

**tail recursive**

```
(defun deletemiddle (list idx1 idx2 &optional (acc '()))
  (cond ((null list) (nreverse acc))
        ((and (<= idx1 -1) (> idx2 0))
         (deletemiddle (cdr list) (1- idx1) (1- idx2) acc))
        (t 
         (deletemiddle (cdr list) (1- idx1) (1- idx2) (cons (car list) acc))))))
```

```
(deletemiddle '(a b c d e f) 2 5)
;; => (A B C F)
```

Comment: what is the impact of ( acc '() ) on the code , I dont understand.
Thanks.

Comment: Also thanks for the answer , more than get a code what I want is understand the process so I can do it by my own , I have been thiking about the process of this but not sure for example : ( a b c d e f ) the index of each will be 
( 0  1   2  3   4   5 ) 
( a  b  c   d   e   f  )     what should I do as condition, if I put ( 2 4 ) the result should be ( a b c e f )  ,  a && condition where two arguments should be true for example 
( 2<= 3 &&  3 < 4 ) in that case both are true , it would be something like ( 2<= 3 < 4)

Comment: It is easier than one thinks: There is an optional argument `curr` which means "current index possition". This function `cdr`s down a list. Means it goes through positions of a list. To remember which at position it is now we have this counter `curr`. If the list came to an end `(null list)` is `t`, then it returns `'()` (nil). If the current position is between the two given arguments `(< idx1 curr idx2)`, then it leaves are current element and calls next recursion `(deletemiddle (cdr list) idx1 idx2 (1+ curr))`.

Comment: Otherwise, it adds (`cons`es) the current element `(car list)` to next recursion's result `(deletemiddle (cdr list) idx1 idx2 (1+ curr))`.

Comment: Maybe your course didn't have tail recursion yet. `acc` is the variable saving temporary result. Here the consing is done on `acc`. It is the `accumulator` for the result.